# iOS - How to do a sliding page view like the new 'tbh' app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I know doing this requires the UIScrollView, but I do not know how to implement it. Just a simple horizontal paging app that you can slide between. It would be preferable to be able to do this in the storyboard view.

Comment: `UIPageViewController` does exactly what you are describing: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller

Comment: I agree that using a UIPageViewController is a good fit for your problem.

Comment: @DonMag It seems like thats the way I'm going to go, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've decided to use the UIPageViewController after some research, thanks!